# Assign CRS for drone imagery

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, water

I am importing TIFF imagery from the Phantom 4 Multispectral drone which does not have predefined CRS. When I double click the layer and go into the source tab and select a CRS, it displays over the wrong location. I've tried the georeferencer which does make it display over the correct location but as I didn't have GCP's, I've had to eyeball it pick points based on the Google Satellite basemap which has produced a bit of a warped image.

Is there another method by which I can assign a CRS to this and make it show over the correct location without having to use the georeferencer? This imagery was taken over Lake Ellerslie in Logan, Queensland, Australia.